# Why My ArrayList always gives wrong data when I use contains?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have 2 `arraylist` and I match them with each other. During the first few minutes I got good results but after that I always got wrong results.

**Code:**

```
                    //Prapering lists for compare
                    ArrayList<String> list_old = new ArrayList<>(tinydb.getListString("list_old"));


                    for(String i: tinydb.getListString("list_old")) {
                        for(String j: tinydb.getListString("list_new")) {
                            if (i.contains(j)) {
                                list_old.remove(i);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

What's wrong in this code?

**List String in TinyDB:**

```
public ArrayList<String> getListString(String key) {
        return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(preferences.getString(key, ""), "‚‗‚")));
    }
```

Comment: Can u post what is the Lists? And what an example would be of bad data you get?

Comment: Can you supply the code for getListString?

Comment: @TungstenX I edited please look it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load your list again. You shouldn't load it again, but an existing one.

```
for(String i : list_old) {
    for (String j: tinydb.getListString("list_new")) {
        if (i.contains(j)) {
            list_old.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: APP is stopping when I make this: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project, PID: 5980
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: We're one step closer to solving your problem then :) You must show us what exactly is `tinydb` and what is the signature of `getListString()` method.

Comment: I edited @Danon

Comment: Are you running this code from multiple threads? Or using `parralelStream()`?

Comment: This is the put string:  tinydb.putListString("list_old", MyArrayList);

Comment: is not stopping when I make like this: for(String i: new ArrayList<>(list_old)) {

Comment: IT's not stopping because you're removing it from a copy of a list, but iterate on the original. You're not working on the same instance of a list.

Comment: Yes you right I find it and I fixt it. Thanks :)